# Installshield: can it generate an .msi file?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

- Can InstallShield generate an `.MSI`
  file?
- What is the difference between the Express and Professional versions of InstallShield?  Is there any reason to get Professional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes it has an option to output a single .msi installer.
2. http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installshield/features.htm

Comment: 1. Yes but make sure you select this type of project as you are creating it. It doesn't appear that you can convert to an MSI if you don't start from one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can.

[See here for a comparison](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installshield/editions.htm)